# How to pass extra arguments to holding event in wp8.1

Tags: c++, events, arguments, windows-phone-8.1

I have a list of elements created programmatically in c++ (not in XAML). I have added an event handler for the holding event, like this:

```
listItem->Holding += ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::HoldingEventHandler(this, &listItem_hold);
```

I have defined the event handler like this:

```
void listItem_hold(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::HoldingRoutedEventArgs^ e);
```

Is there a way to add my own data to the HoldingRoutedEventArgs object so I can access it from inside the event handler?
I tried creating a derived class from HoldingRoutedEventArgs, but it's sealed so I can't use it a as base class.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Rob Caplan! that seems like a great solution for me!

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You don't trigger the Holding event and so don't control what arguments are passed.

Indirectly there are a couple of options depending on what data you want and where you want to stow it. Here are two to think about:

You can encapsulate the extra events in the event handler itself. Create a class with properties for whatever extra information you want and with the event handler method. Wire the Holding event up to the method in your custom object. That object can either do whatever is needed within itself or raise its own event with a custom argument list.

If you want the extra data to be attached to the sending listItem then you could stow it in either a dictionary keyed on the item or create an attached property and attach it to the item. See [Custom attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965327.aspx) on MSDN.